# vstirbu/InstagramPlugin on Steroids

Tags: phonegap-plugins, instagram, cordova-plugins

I am attempting to use vstirbu's Instagram plugin (https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin) for Cordova with my app. My app is using the Appgyver Steroids platform. after adding the plugin to my build the app builds fine and I am able to install it on the phone fine. there is only one page where the Instagram functionality is needed and when that page is opened I get the "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.Instagram.share')" error. are there other Instagram plugins available that I might try out or are there steps to initialize the plug in that I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you built a debug scanner version with the plugin. I had this issue with a BLE plugin. I was trying to reference the plugin as `window.plugins.nameOfPluginObject` and it didn't exist. It didn't exist that way, but it did exist as `nameOfPluginObject`. I could make calls to it that way. `nameOfPluginObject.someMethod();`.

See if you can debug the app in Safari / Chrome and use the console to type `typeof window.plugins.Instagram` and then `typeof Instagram`. I am guessing `typeof Instagram` returns `object` and the other returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, I am using an Ad Hock debug build. In the debugger on Safari both typeof Instagram and typeof window.plugins.Instagram return undefined. I am rebuilding the app via appgyver now as I assume this means it is not installed.

Comment: What does the Appgyver plugin build setting look like on your app? Something like this? `[
  {"source":"https://github.com/AppGyver/PushNotifications.git"}]`

Comment: I am not sure why but the build did not have the plug in installed. I tried a few more builds and eventually it did work.

Comment: How did you access the Instragram object? Was it located in `window.plugins.Instagram` or just `Instagram`?

Answer (score 0):

Is Cordova loaded in that page? Are you making the calls after `deviceready` (although if it's the console, I suppose you're alright). The plugin JavaScripts are loaded when `cordova.js` loads. Also, you can extract the IPA file (just rename it to .zip) and see if the plugin files are correctly in the package (although if it builds correctly, it should be fine).